# HTML Validator in Javascript/PHP? ( not necessarily XML )

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, dom

I'm looking for something like http://validator.nu/, I'll be validating html input ( string ) and I want to notify the user if there are any missing end tags, whether a certain element can't have a certain attribute, things of that nature ( HTML 4.01 Strict validation basically ).

Sidenote: I won't be dealing with XML/DTDs, and I don't want to correct the user input like how http://htmlpurifier.org/ does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo, I ended up using the official [W3 Validator SOAP](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) web service because it's far superior to Tidy's warnings and it's just the perfect tool that I needed. Did have to learn some SOAP and namespace rules, but it was worth it :)

Answer (score 4):

For HTML Validation done from PHP, the [tidy extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) might do just what you want :

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML
>   clean and repair utility which allows
>   you to not only clean and otherwise
>   manipulate HTML documents, but also
>   traverse the document tree

The example given on the [tidy::__construct](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.construct.php) is like this :

```
$html = <<< HTML

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<p>paragraph <bt />
text</p>
</body></html>

HTML;

$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->ParseString($html);

$tidy->CleanRepair();

if ($tidy->errorBuffer) {
    var_dump($tidy->errorBuffer);
}
```

And gives this output :

```
string 'line 8 column 14 - Error: <bt> is not recognized!
line 8 column 14 - Warning: discarding unexpected <bt>' (length=104)
```

A couple or other methods seem interesting too, btw ;-)

Note you need to have this extension installed / enabled on your webserver, though -- there should be a "tidy" section in the output of `phpinfo()`.