# How to check if the HTML code is valid via PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

I am providing my users to create their own widgets on their profile pages.Widgets are created by HTML codes by user input.

But Sometimes, if user enter an invalid html code, widget field is corrupting. To avoid this situation, I must be sure the html code that user entered is valid.

My question is how to check a html code validation via PHP or Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Validator in Javascript/PHP? ( not necessarily XML )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336108/html-validator-in-javascript-php-not-necessarily-xml)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [tidy](http://php.net/tidy) php extension;

There are a number of things that you can do with it, but for your case I think you could just use the `repairString` method to get the **clean** version of the user input and compare it with the initial version,

Something like this:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$clean = $tidy->repairString($user_input);
```

If no changes were made during the `repairString` method; `$user_input` and `$clean` should be the same.

Comment: I've always found tidy to be really unreliable. Last time I tried to use it, it insisted on making changes to my (valid) markup that I really didn't want. I ended up having to perform a find and replace, then run tidy, then run find and replace again to work around the problem.

Comment: @Quentin and that did not depend on the doctype?

Comment: No, the Doctype was immaterial.

Comment: @Quentin in this case thanks for sharing; this might be very useful in the future

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tidy just worked well. I'm now repairing all user inputs with tidy and then save them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [SO question / answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030392/x-html-validator-in-php). The [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php)-Class may validate your HTML with PHP.