# Validating tinymce editor data on server side

Tags: php, validation, tinymce

I want to validate the data entered in tinymce editor in server side in PHP. I need to allow standard html tags but need to avoid scripts and style tags attached to html elements. Please help me.

Comment: [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336108/html-validator-in-javascript-php-not-necessarily-xml

Comment: I want to validate the content to see whether it has script tag style tag etc instead of modifying the content.

Answer (score 0):

use `DOMDocument` to load the html generated with tinymce and search for your restricted html with `DOMXPath`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the javascript `strip_tags` function mentioned here: [TinyMCE Paste As Plain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122451/tinymce-paste-as-plain-text)

You need to apply this before you send the code to the server.

Comment: Just like your server side should be validating your regular input controls that could be accepting text that is attempting a SQL injection, you need to validate on the server that text seemingly from TinyMCE doesn't have malicious scripts. You can't trust client-side code as it's [trivial to bypass validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775123/edit-and-replay-xhr-chrome-firefox-etc) and special characters and tags won't get automatically escaped or stripped by TinyMCE.

Comment: that is correct - server side measures sdould be in place too, but strip_tags is one way to make it more difficult

Comment: Won’t `strip_tags` get rid of the standard html tags the OP wants to keep?

Comment: not necessarily, the second paramter of strip_tags allows to insert allowed tags that do not get tripped